# Simple way to reset the dropdown list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

i want to clear only 3 elements in dropdown list. how to do by iteration i.e indexbased would be fine.

Here is how my dropdown looks.

```
<div id = "Dropdown">
    <select id="dropdownlist" class="trace dropdown" name="dropdownlistitems">                  
        <option value="ID1" selected="selected">--Please Select--</option> 
        <option value="ID2">ID2text</option>
        <option value="ID3">ID3text</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$('#dropdownlist option').each(function (index, option) {
    if(index!=0)
    {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

This will remove each option tag that the loop iterates through (except, of course, the first one)

Comment: ya, some wat of wat u mean, instead of this i tried like this  if (index !== 0)
            
                $(listid + " option[value=" + option.value + "]").remove();.. urs should be fine..

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('#dropdownlist option:lt(3)').remove();
```

This selects the first 3 options and removes them.

Comment: how if i have integer index.. how to do it? pls post syntax

Comment: What do you mean by have a integer index?

Comment: i mean, i have a loop like this, i m able to iterate i.e   $('#dropdownlist option').each(function (index, option) {
                // option will contain your item
              
                if(index !== 0)
                //remove logic based on index  

            }); but i want to remove the item based on index. how to do?